# Multi vespa docker containers per host?

Tags: docker, vespa

PB: I have tried to deploy 5 vespa containers on two different hosts but I do not succeed to make my vespa nodes up.

I named my 3 containers vespa0, vespa1 , vespa2 with port 8080, 8081, 8082 respectively on the first host and vespa3, vespa4 with port 8080, 8081 respectively

I start vespa containers this way

```
sudo docker run --detach --net=host --name vespa0 --hostname admin_paul0 --privileged --volume $PWD/sample-apps:/vespa-sample-apps --publish 8080:8080 vespaengine/vespa
```

Then I deploy the application with:

```
sudo docker exec vespa0 bash -c '/opt/vespa/bin/vespa-deploy prepare /vespa-sample-apps/site_search_multi_node_on_multi_server/src/main/application && /opt/vespa/bin/vespa-deploy activate'
```

When i write the command

```
sudo docker exec vespa0 bash -c '/opt/vespa/bin/vespa-get-cluster-state'
```

The cluster detects the nodes on the two hosts but only one is up.

```
Cluster site:
site/distributor/0: down
site/distributor/1: down
site/distributor/3: down
site/distributor/4: up
site/storage/0: down
site/storage/1: down
site/storage/3: down
site/storage/4: up
```

hereby the configuration of the applications

host.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Copyright 2017 Yahoo Holdings. Licensed under the terms of the Apache 2.0 license. See LICENSE in the project root. -->
    <hosts>
     <host name="admin_paul0">
    <alias>admin_paul0</alias>
  </host>

  <host name="stateless_paul0">
    <alias>stateless_paul0</alias>
  </host>

  <host name="content_paul0">
    <alias>content_paul0</alias>
  </host>

  <host name="content_paul1">
    <alias>content_paul1</alias>
  </host>

  <host name="stateless_paul1">
    <alias>stateless_paul1</alias>
  </host>
</hosts>
```

services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Copyright 2017 Yahoo Holdings. Licensed under the terms of the Apache 2.0 license. See LICENSE in the project root. -->
<services version="1.0">
  <admin version="2.0">
    <adminserver hostalias="admin_paul0"/>
    <configservers>
      <configserver hostalias="admin_paul0"/>
    </configservers>
  </admin>

  <container id="container" version="1.0">
    <document-api/>
    <search/>
    <nodes>
      <node hostalias="stateless_paul0"/>
      <node hostalias="stateless_paul1"/>
      <node hostalias="content_paul0"/>
      <node hostalias="content_paul1"/>
    </nodes>
  </container>

  <content id="site" version="1.0">
    <redundancy>1</redundancy>
    <documents>
      <document type="site" mode="index"/>
    </documents>
    <nodes>
      <node hostalias="content_paul0" distribution-key="0"/>
      <node hostalias="content_paul1" distribution-key="1"/>
      <node hostalias="stateless_paul0" distribution-key="3"/>
      <node hostalias="stateless_paul1" distribution-key="4"/>
    </nodes>
  </content>
</services>
```

Do you have any tips that will make it work? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to isolate the network to make this work as Vespa uses a range of other ports that would otherwise conflict (i.e no --net=host). Running on baremetal hosts you could use the macvlan network driver to assign the container a cross-host ip, otherwise you would need to setup NPT or something similar.